# Lustre: find where inodes are being used

Tags: inode, lustre

I'm looking for a command that will list the number of files across several directories simultaneously. Currently, I can do this for a single directory:

```
lfs find DIRECTORY -type f | wc -l
```

But this is tedious to do iteratively. Can someone think of a way to do this more like [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117094/82522), but with lfs find, as opposed to gnu find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command seems to produce the exact same output:

```
lfs find -type f DIRECTORY | sed -r "s#(.*)/.*#\1#" | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1 -n
```

Edit: If you want to group files according to some fixed directory depth:

```
lfs find -type f DIRECTORY | sed -r "s#((/[^/]*){0,DEPTH})/.*#\1#" | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1 -n
```